# How To Loop xml attribute on c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, asp.net-core

I have xml data like this :

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<searchdetail totalRecords=\"4\" pageSize=\"4\" requestId=\"71505ed0-a936-4f02-96ed-
44f42cfd5f3f\">
<details>
<transaction>
<player playerId="D1_67190" partnerId="GrabFood"/>
<detail transactionId="439077816" transactionDate="20210816 10:48:07" currency="IDR"
merchant="foodpanda" transactionType="data" handId="121125555"/>
</transaction>
</details>
</searchdetail>
```

I want do a looping for player element and detail to get their attribute

Comment: This isn't how Stack Overflow works.  Read [ask].

Comment: Sorry what do u mean ?

Comment: Well, it's really unclear what you're asking for.  Can you make it clearer, perhaps with sample output?

Comment: Hi @Mulzahrian, did you want to get `playerId` and `partnerId`? Or get their corresponding value `D1_67190` and `GrabFood`?

Comment: yes and transactionId and currency to

Comment: Hi @Mulzahrian, so what you want to get their value(`D1_67190`,`GrabFood`, `439077816`, `IDR`), right?

Comment: yes i want to get that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");  //load your xml...
    
foreach (var detail in doc.Descendants("details"))
{
    foreach(var transaction in detail.Descendants("transaction"))
    {
        var playerId = transaction.Element("player").Attribute("partnerId").Value;
        var partnerId = transaction.Element("player").Attribute("partnerId").Value;
        var transactionId = transaction.Element("detail").Attribute("transactionId").Value;
        var currency = transaction.Element("detail").Attribute("currency").Value;
    }
}
```

If `transaction` here is **not an array**, no need to loop and you could get the data like:

```
foreach (var detail in doc.Descendants("details"))
{        
    var playerId = detail.Element("transaction").Element("player").Attribute("partnerId").Value;
    //...
}
```

Comment: how i can make detail element in same looping with player element ?

Comment: No, you can't. They are different node, so you cannot loop in player. You need repeat the GetElementsByTagName and loop. If you want to in one loop to get both player and detail  element., i will edit my answer.

Comment: yea i want to get a both player and detail element

Comment: in one loop to get a both of player and detail

Comment: Hi @Mulzahrian, please check my updated answer.